# How can I get an adaptive card list from Bot Framework v4 again?

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

This is the source of Dialogs/MainDialog.cs that brings my adaptive card.

If you already select a card once in the ShowCardStepAsync() section below, I would like to show you one more card list to make a re-selection.
I want you to tell me what to do at this time.

```
namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
{
public class MainDialog : ComponentDialog
{
    protected readonly ILogger _logger;


    public MainDialog(ILogger<MainDialog> logger)
        : base(nameof(MainDialog))
    {

    _logger = logger;

        // Define the main dialog and its related components.
        AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(nameof(ChoicePrompt)));
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            ChoiceCardStepAsync,
            ShowCardStepAsync,
        }));

        // The initial child Dialog to run.
        InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
    }
    // 1. Prompts the user if the user is not in the middle of a dialog.
    // 2. Re-prompts the user when an invalid input is received.
    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ChoiceCardStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("MainDialog.ChoiceCardStepAsync");

        // Create the PromptOptions which contain the prompt and re-prompt messages.
        // PromptOptions also contains the list of choices available to the user.
        var options = new PromptOptions()
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("카드를 선택 해 주세요 "),
            RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("올바르지 않은 선택입니다. 카드를 다시 선택해 주세요"),
            Choices = GetChoices(),
        };

        // Prompt the user with the configured PromptOptions.
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ChoicePrompt), options, cancellationToken);
    }

    // Send a Rich Card response to the user based on their choice.
    // This method is only called when a valid prompt response is parsed from the user's response to the ChoicePrompt.
    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ShowCardStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("MainDialog.ShowCardStepAsync");

        // Cards are sent as Attachments in the Bot Framework.
        // So we need to create a list of attachments for the reply activity.
        var attachments = new List<Attachment>();

        // Reply to the activity we received with an activity.
        var reply = MessageFactory.Attachment(attachments);

        // Decide which type of card(s) we are going to show the user
        switch (((FoundChoice)stepContext.Result).Value)
        {
            case "Adaptive Card":
                // Display an Adaptive Card
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment());
                break;
            case "Animation Card":
                // Display an AnimationCard.
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetAnimationCard().ToAttachment());
                break;
            case "Audio Card":
                // Display an AudioCard
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetAudioCard().ToAttachment());
                break;
            case "Hero Card":
                // Display a HeroCard.
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetHeroCard().ToAttachment());
                break;
            case "Receipt Card":
                // Display a ReceiptCard.
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetReceiptCard().ToAttachment());
                break;
            case "Signin Card":
                // Display a SignInCard.
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetSigninCard().ToAttachment());
                break;
            case "Thumbnail Card":
                // Display a ThumbnailCard.
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetThumbnailCard().ToAttachment());
                break;
            case "Video Card":
                // Display a VideoCard
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetVideoCard().ToAttachment());
                break;
            default:
                // Display a carousel of all the rich card types.
                reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment());
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetAnimationCard().ToAttachment());
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetAudioCard().ToAttachment());
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetHeroCard().ToAttachment());
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetReceiptCard().ToAttachment());
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetSigninCard().ToAttachment());
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetThumbnailCard().ToAttachment());
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetVideoCard().ToAttachment());
                break;
        }

        // Send the card(s) to the user as an attachment to the activity
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);

        // Give the user instructions about what to do next
        var ment = MessageFactory.Text("다른 선택지를 골라 주세요.");

        // Prompt the user with the configured PromptOptions.
        //return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ChoicePrompt), new PromptOptions, cancellationToken);
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(ment, cancellationToken);
        //await ChoiceCardStepAsync(stepContext, cancellationToken);

        return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();



    }

    private IList<Choice> GetChoices()
    {
        var cardOptions = new List<Choice>()
        {
            new Choice() { Value = "Adaptive Card", Synonyms = new List<string>() { "adaptive" } },
            new Choice() { Value = "Animation Card", Synonyms = new List<string>() { "animation" } },
            new Choice() { Value = "Audio Card", Synonyms = new List<string>() { "audio" } },
            new Choice() { Value = "Hero Card", Synonyms = new List<string>() { "hero" } },
            new Choice() { Value = "Receipt Card", Synonyms = new List<string>() { "receipt" } },
            new Choice() { Value = "Signin Card", Synonyms = new List<string>() { "signin" } },
            new Choice() { Value = "Thumbnail Card", Synonyms = new List<string>() { "thumbnail", "thumb" } },
            new Choice() { Value = "Video Card", Synonyms = new List<string>() { "video" } },
            new Choice() { Value = "All cards", Synonyms = new List<string>() { "all" } },
        };

        return cardOptions;
    }
}
}
```

To explain the sequence,

**
1. The card buttons and the card buttons are listed.

2. Select one of the buttons to show the card of the selected type.
3. Show the card and send the card re-selection comment and card list again at the same time.
4. This continues until the End button is selected.**

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```cs
stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(nameof(MainDialog))
```

This will actually restart the current dialog you are in which is **MainDialog** 
You can do this by adding a few conditions depending on what the use chose.

But keep in mind you should always end your dialog with

```cs
stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
```

Or you will be stuck in an endless loop of replacing the current dialog and restarting over over, so in your case the **EndDialogAsync()** should be only when the user selects the **End Button** otherwise you need to **ReplaceDialogAsync()** to restart it